# Unable to stop the Timer by changing the Boolean value to false in Swift

Tags: swift5

I tried running the following code but the timer won't stop after counting till "0" seconds.

> Desired OutPut :  5 seconds. 4 seconds. 3 seconds. 2 seconds. 1
> seconds. 0 seconds.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var seconds = 5
    var value = true
    
    @IBAction
    func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(secondsRemaining), userInfo: nil, repeats: value)
    }
            
    @objc
    func secondsRemaining() {
        print("\(seconds) seconds.")
        
        if seconds > 0{
            seconds -= 1
        }else{
            value = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you schedule a timer passing `true` as `repeats`, that means that this timer will continue to occur unless you explicitly call `invalidate()` function on the returning instance and set it to `nil`.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var seconds = 5
    var timer: Timer?
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(secondsRemaining), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
   @objc func secondsRemaining() {
        print("\(seconds) seconds.")
        if seconds > 0 {
            seconds -= 1
        } else {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
    }
}
```